# Display view from external HTML

Tags: html, angular

I would like to display a view on page from HTML from external database using Angular 2.
For example I have a html string in component.ts like below:

```
htmlString = '<div style="color: red">Hello world!</div>';
```

And this is my html file:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Instead to get red font "Hello word!" sentence it returns me only tags on my page. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i think you also need to put a pipe to allow html in string (safe html) ..
something like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

and use like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString | safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still the same problem. It returns only tags instead view.